# How to get client ip and server ip of system?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am new to learn JEE6.I need to know to get the client and server IP address using JEE6.
Is there any other way to get these ip .

Comment: The question is very vague. A short description of what you are trying to achieve would help!

Answer (score 0):

you can get client IP using request object.

```
request.getRemoteAddr();
```

Server IP will be the IP of machine where your application will be deployed.